# Remove the Text in C#.net

Tags: c#

I have a string like,

```
string str;

str = "This is my new string. "<script>" Hi this is XYZ "</script>"";
```

Now I want to remove the text, from `"<script>"` to `"</script>"` including the  tags by using C#.net code.

Thanks,

Comment: Specifically the script tags or any generic HTML tags. Do you also want to support nested tags? What about self-closing tags?

Comment: you want to remove the text from str variable  ? did you try str=string.Empty ?

Comment: Which bit of text do you want to remove - it is not clear? What have you tried already?

Comment: could you rephrase the question, it makes no sense. What would str look like after the operation?

Comment: What text do you want to remove? What have you tried?

Comment: You've mucked up your quotes in that most recent edit - where are the quotes meant to be - weren't they correct before your edit?

Comment: Check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847538/remove-html-tags-or-script-tags-in-c-sharp-string-and-also-in-client-using-javas

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Regex](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasad_1/RegExpPSD12062005021717AM/RegExpPSD.aspx).

With that you can locate it and delete then.

This should get everything between script tags "`<script>[^<]+</script>`"

Comment: In Normal situations i would agree but in the question he gives this seems a vallid answer.

Comment: What's the link supposed to be it resolves to `http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasad_1/RegExpPSD12062005021717AM/RegExpPSD.aspx` which doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: it should give a tutorial for regex in c#

Comment: @ChrisF maybe some time out, who knows, not a exact science (it should be tough)

Answer (score 1):

this is what i use to remove html tags in a string

```
public static string ClearHtmlTags(string html)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(html)) 
                return html;

            html = html.Trim();
            string[] hs = html.Split("<>".ToArray());
            bool skip = false;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in hs)
            {
                if (!skip)
                    sb.Append(s);

                skip = !skip;
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

and with a simple modify you will get your method

```
public static string ClearHtmlTags(string html)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(html)) 
                return html;

            html = html.Trim();
            string[] hs = html.Split("<>".ToArray());
            bool skip = false;
            bool skipTag = false;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in hs)
            {
                if (!skip)
                {
                    if (!skipTag)
                        sb.Append(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    skipTag = s == "script";
                }

                skip = !skip;
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, "<script>([a-z]|[A-Z])*</script>", "");
```

now this would only allow alphanumeric text within the script tags

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it'll miss the spaces and pretty much everything that one might find in a `<script>` element.

Answer (score -10):

If you want to remove text from specific length e.g

```
"my name is testing"
```

here you want to remove `is`
just use `indexof` function later on use `substring` method for replace string with null or some thing else.

In c# you can filter your string like this or user regex before enter the data

Comment: This is not a comment, it's an answer. Perhaps that's the problem? You can remove it by clicking the "delete" link.